# Creating a Timeline Plot Represented as Line Segments

Tags: r, date, plot

I am looking to create a plot in R where the y-axis represents unique `id` values, and the x-axis is a timeline. Each `id` should be represented by a line segment connecting two points: a `start` date and an `end` date. Below is an example dataset:

```
id<-c("id1","id2","id3")
start<-c("2010-02-01","2010-04-05","2010-03-08")
end<-c("2013-11-10","2013-01-01","2011-05-07")
data<-data.frame(id,start,end)
```

I need assistance with code or guidance on how to create this plot, with each `id` having its own line segment between its respective `start` and `end` dates. Any help or suggestions on how to approach this task would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a representation of what I'm looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this manually in base R by first creating a blank plot them adding in `segments`. I also added in `points` to distinguish the ends. You can play around with the parameters to tweak the look to exactly what you want:

```
plot(range(data$start, data$end), c(1, nrow(data)), 
     type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
segments(x0 = data$start, x1 = data$end, y0 = 1:nrow(data), lwd = 3)
points(x = c(data$start, data$end), y = rep(1:nrow(data), 2), pch = 20, cex = 3)
axis(1, at = seq.Date(min(data$start), max(data$end), by = "month"),
     labels = seq.Date(min(data$start), max(data$end), by = "month"))
axis(2, at = 1:nrow(data), labels = data$id)
```

[image]

You may also be interested in the [`vistime`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vistime/vignettes/vistime-vignette.html) package (but I personally find it a bit easier to control specifics in the above approach):

```
vistime::vistime(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Im having some issues with the script. When applied to the complete dataset I get this error: ```Error in plot.window(...) : se necesitan valores finitos de 'xlim'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf```

Comment: my ```end``` and ```start``` variables are "Date" class. Is this an issue? Should they have "character" class?

Comment: They should be `Date` class - this allows mathematical functions on them. Do you have `NA` values? If so, do `max(..., na.rm = TRUE)`, `min(..., na.rm = TRUE)`, and `range(..., na.rm = TRUE)` - if this doesnt work, try editing your question to include the structure of your real data (ie, paste the output of `dput(your_real_data)`) and I'll see what I can do!

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot!